# Where are the WPF effects defined?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, effects, pixel-shader

I am wondering where the WPF effects such as `Blur` is defined? They are pixel shaders, right? Is there a way to peek into their implementation?

Comment: Well, [`System.Windows.Media.Effects.Effect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect.aspx) lives in the PresentationCore.dll assembly. Maybe if you decompiled that...

Comment: Thanks Bolt, yes. I wasn't sure where they were. Just wanted to take a look in the reflector :O

Comment: It looks like it's an unmanaged/unsafe effect. I guess they did it for performance reasons.

Comment: I posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the PresentationCore.dll assembly, where [`System.Windows.Media.Effects.Effect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect.aspx) and its derivatives are defined. If you take it apart using Reflector you should be able to find the signatures and, hopefully, any implementation details.

It would seem that pixel shaders are effectively used by, well, [`ShaderEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect.aspx)...